# Highlight custom sections of code in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an extension for VS Code that allows to highlight (or color or bold) custom sections of the code?

Comment: Maybe, can you give an example of "custom sections"?  Can they be uniquely recognized by regex?

Comment: What I mean is that I mark a certain section manually and "highlight" it

Comment: If you have a unique start and end point that can be identified by a regex you could use the extension "Highlight" https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight to change the color or fontweight of custom sections of your code.  If you need further assistance, edit your question with how you "mark" the sections and the languages you are using.